# Sort lines by number of words per line

Tags: text-processing, sort

Given input:

```
hello: world foo bar baz
bar:
baz: bin boop bop fiz bang beep
bap: bim bam bop
boatkeeper: poughkeepsie
```

I would like to sort it into most words at the top, to least at the end, like so:

```
baz: bin boop bop fiz bang beep
hello: world foo bar baz
bap: bim bam bop
boatkeeper: poughkeepsie
bar:
```

How would I do this with `sort` or some other tool?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to sort by number of words not sort by line length (with your sample input the line with the most words is also  the longest but that might not always be the case) ?

Comment: Yes. The line with the most words isn't necessarily the longest in general. e.g. I want `bin: bop boop` before `boatkeeper: poughkeepsie`. If two lines share the same number of words, I would prefer the ties to be alphabetized, but that's not a requirement.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
awk '{print NF,$0}' file | sort -nr | cut -d' ' -f 2-
```

We use `awk` to prefix the number of fields to each line. We then `sort` by that number and remove it with `cut`.

Comment: This worked. Was wondering why the order was reversed, but I see your edit now.

Answer (score 6):

In recent GNU `awk` one can use `PROCINFO` array to define many internal parameters including order in which array elements are printed (controlled by element `"sorted_in"`). Thus we can built and array indexed with the value of `NF" "NR`, which elements have value of `$0` and print it in desired output, in your case that would be `"@ind_num_desc"`:

```
awk '{a[NF" "NR]=$0}END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_desc"; for(i in a) print a[i]}' file
```

Comment: +1 was thinking the same thing: however one should perhaps note that it will have the side effect of de-duplicating the input

Comment: @steeldriver you are absolutely correct, I edited my answer, should  be fine now.

Comment: This now preserves the original ordering between records with the same number of fields, instead of sorting on the words as a secondary sort key.  If your keys were `NF" "$0" "NR`, you'd only have `NR` as a fallback / duplicate-handling mechanism.

Comment: @PeterCordes but that would reverse the order of words, I see no way to resolve ties alphabetically other that by definition own function `cmp_func()` - gnu awk allows that.

Answer (score 5):

Perl one-liner:

```perl
print sort { split(' ',$a) <=> split(' ',$b) } <>;
```

If you want to break ties using alphabetical order:

```perl
print sort { split(' ',$a) <=> split(' ',$b) or $a cmp $b } <>;
```

Answer (score 4):

Through python.

```
s = '''hello: world foo bar baz
bar:
baz: bin boop bop fiz bang beep
bap: bim bam bop'''.splitlines()
for i in sorted(s, key=lambda x: len(x.split()), reverse=True):
    print(i)
```

**or**

```
with open('/path/to/the/input/file') as f:
    m = f.readlines()
    for i in sorted(m, key=lambda x: len(x.split()), reverse=True):
        print(i, end="")
```